# Conversion of data (one column) with a stringr

Tags: r, dataframe, stringr

I have a table called DATA_SET.This table contains one column with six different 
 cases of data.

```
    #DATA_SET
    DATA_SET<-data.frame(
           CUSTOMS_RATE=c("20","15+0,41 eur/kg","10+0,1 eur/kg max.17","0,1 
            eur/l max.17","0,04 eur/kg max.10","NA")
                        )

    View(DATA_SET)

    #DATA_SET1
      DATA_SET1<-data.frame(
      RATE="",
      SPECIFIC_RATE="",
      MAXIMUM_RATE=""
                          )
```

So my intention is to divide this column into three different columns in order to continue with other statistical operations (calculation of averages, etc.) like table (DATA_SET 1) below.

[image]

So can anybody help me how to transform this table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, `separate` would be a better option, but in this case, the positions of the numbers are not the same in each row, (sometimes missing too).  So, we are using `str_extract` to individually extract the values

```
library(tidyverse)
DATA_SET %>%
   mutate(CUSTOMS_RATE = str_replace_all(CUSTOMS_RATE, ",", "."),
          RATE = str_extract(CUSTOMS_RATE, "^[0-9]+(?=\\+|$)"), 
          SPECIFIC_RATE = str_extract(CUSTOMS_RATE, "\\d+\\.\\d+"), 
          MAXIMUM_RATE = str_extract(CUSTOMS_RATE, "(?<=max\\.)\\d+")) %>% 
  select(2:4) %>%
  mutate_all(as.numeric)
# RATE SPECIFIC_RATE MAXIMUM_RATE
#1   20          <NA>         <NA>
#2   15          0.41         <NA>
#3   10           0.1           17
#4 <NA>           0.1           17
#5 <NA>          0.04           10
#6 <NA>          <NA>         <NA>
```

---

Or use `str_replace` to create a single delimiter and then use `separate`

```
DATA_SET %>% 
    mutate(CUSTOMS_RATE = str_replace_all(CUSTOMS_RATE, ",", ".") %>% 
                          str_replace("\\+?([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)", "+\\1") %>% 
                          str_replace_all("[A-Za-z/ ]+\\.?", "+")) %>% 
    separate(CUSTOMS_RATE, into = c("RATE", "SPECIFIC_RATE", "MAXIMUM_RATE"),
                   sep="\\+", convert = TRUE)
```

Comment: There is mistake only in first row. Namely this code give "NA" in all three columns of first row.In accordance with picture DATA_SET1  first column and first row should have "20" . So please correct if is possible.Thank you in advance

Comment: Excellent! Thank you Akrun